# Update ProgressBar within MainThread in AndroidAPP

Tags: java, android, progress

I have **2 buttons** as well as a **progressbar**.
Now I want to count from 0 - 100 and update the progressbar with the counter. Unfortunately this count is so fast, that I will not see a progress (I can only see the progressbar jump from 0 to 100 within a 'millisecond'.).

This is what I tried so far, however the same thing happens as before.

I **click the button** to start the counter, the **app becomes unresponsive** (I calculate within the mainThread, so that is OKAY (and exactly what I want to accomplish here(!))) and shortly after sets the **progressbar to 100**. **Nothing in between**.

Now if you could head me into the correct direction, that'd be highly appreciated! :)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addButtonListeners();
    }

    public void addButtonListeners() {
        Button firstButton, secondButton;
        final ProgressBar pgBar;

        firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_button);
        secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second_button);
        pgBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "First Button was pressed.");
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    countProgBarUp(pgBar, i);
                }
            }
        });

        secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Second Button was pressed.");

            }
        });

    }

    public void countProgBarUp(ProgressBar pgBar, int counter) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            pgBar.setProgress(counter);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: look into a countdown timer. thats what you should use to count down and update a progress bar. the way you are doing it is not the way you should be.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will give this a shot. I know updating the progressbar from within the mainthread is bad but that's exactly what this example should show ;) It's the first step to an introduction to threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI becomes unresponsive because you are doing this on the main thread and sleeping. If you do not return from the `onClick()` then the main thread cannot handle UI changes, such as displaying your new progress. Only the main thread can update UI components and draw them. It is often called the UI thread because of this.

You could try creating a `Runnable` which updates the progress bar to the new count. Create a `Handler` which is bound to the UI thread and call `postDelayed()` for the `Handler` and give it an instance of the `Runnable`.  Then in the `Runnable` just post it again as long as you haven't reached you max progress.

Comment: Ahh, I entirely forgot about the drawing. Yeah, of course. Wow, sometimes asking these dumb questions is the only way to learn.. :/ Thanks!